# optimum way to join the following two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Okay i have 2 tables,

**url_table**

```
id  
link_url
```

**tag table**

```
id
link_tags
```

i'd like to join them, to create a view or table like,

```
id ,link_tag1, link_tag2, link_tag3.....
```

sample data: url_table

```
[1 | w3schools.com] 
[2 | php.net]
```

sample_data: tag_table:

```
[1 | html]
[1 | javascript]
[2 | php]
```

required table

```
[1 | html,javascript]
[2 | php]
```

How best can i do this without using too much queries?

Comment: Show sample data with the result you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` function for this:

```
SELECT u.url
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag)
FROM url_table u
JOIN tag_table t
 ON u.id = t.id
GROUP BY u.url
```

Note:  In the example the `JOIN` doesn't really add anything as `ID` and `tag` could just be had from the `tag_table`, but I included it assuming there's more than just the sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id, group_concat(`Link_Tag` separator ',') as mTags
FROM tag_table
Group by ID
```

As your results don't really render the URL, there's no need for a join.  Everything can be done direct on the tag_table.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this :**

```
    Select a.id,b.link_tag1,b.link_tag2,b.link_tag3 from url_table a
    inner join tag_table b
    on a.id= b.id
 -- where {clause here}
;
```